# Get upsert result code or confirmation from MongoDB C#

Tags: mongodb, insert, upsert

I would like to find out if MongoDB has performed an insert, or updated the record. How do I find that out through the C# driver?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just noticed that GetLastError() command may be useful. But I'd love to hear about the best practice from professionals :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of official c# driver has SafeMode enabled by default, this means that all operations return result of operation via getLastError method. Also SafeMode was renamed into WriteConcern.